# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, jtable

can someome explain me this error, i can't understand what is going on?
im tring to reset a JTable so every time i call cargartablaclientes method it doesn't add more rows. 
and then load the table

```
public void agregarnuevafila(javax.swing.JTable Table)
{
   //Define temp como una variable de tipo DefaultTableModel
   DefaultTableModel temp = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();
   Object nuevo[] = {"","","","","","",""};

   //Inserta la nueva fila al objeto correspondiente
   temp.addRow(nuevo);
}

public void cargartablaclientes(javax.swing.JTable jTable1, String fech)
{
    int linea = 1;
    reiniciarJTable(jTable1);
    try 
    { 
        Connection cn = sql.Conectar();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM datos where fecha= '"+fech+"' ";
        ResultSet rs = sql.stmt.executeQuery(query);
        rs.first();        
        if (rs!=null)
        {
            do 
            {
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("serie"), linea, 0);
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("placa"), linea, 1);
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("fecha"), linea, 2);
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("hora_entrada"), linea, 3);
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("tipo"), linea, 4);
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("hora_salida"), linea, 5);
                jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString("total"), linea, 6);
                linea++;

                if (linea >= 4)
                {
                    agregarnuevafila(jTable1);
                }                    
                rs.next(); 
            }while(rs!=null);
        }            
    }   
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);            
    }    

}

public static void reiniciarJTable(javax.swing.JTable Tabla){
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) Tabla.getModel();
    while(modelo.getRowCount()>0)modelo.removeRow(0);

    TableColumnModel modCol = Tabla.getColumnModel();
    while(modCol.getColumnCount()>0)modCol.removeColumn(modCol.getColumn(0));
}
```

and the exception display in the console is this

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(SwingUtilities2.java:1905)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2582)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)
at BaseSQL.modelo.cargartablaclientes(modelo.java:197)
at ParqueoSQL.ParqueoAstor.<init>(ParqueoAstor.java:44)
at ParqueoSQL.ParqueoAstor$17.run(ParqueoAstor.java:1178)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Seems you're trying to get the element at index 0 (so the first element), while there's 0 elements to get (empty).

Comment: it's hard to read your method names if they're all lowercase `cargartablaclientes` change it to `cargarTablaClientes`, then, your variables should start with lowerCamelCase as well as your method names: `javax.swing.JTable Table` to `javax.swing.JTable table`

Comment: `rs.first();` you might want to move that line inside the `if` statement

Comment: Also if you want help in spanish, there's [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) and don't forget that, for better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DefaultTableModel temp = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();
Object nuevo[] = {"","","","","","",""};

//Inserta la nueva fila al objeto correspondiente
temp.addRow(nuevo);
```

Your `TableModel` has 0 columns. You need to specify the number of columns you want when you create the `JTable`:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 7);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```